# ¿Cómo resolver loss: nan y accuracy: 0.0000e + 00 en un problema LSTM? Tensorflow 2.x

Tags: python, tensorflow, regresión-lineal

Estoy trabajando en un **problema de LSTM**. Estoy tratando de predecir el **tipo de personalidad MBTI** (prueba de Myers-Briggs) según **clasificación de texto** (hay 16 tipos de personalidad).

Tengo un **archivo csv**, que fue **preprocesado**: *se eliminaron las stopwords, fue lematizado, tokenizado, secuenciado y paddeado*. El dataframe no tiene ningún valor `NaN` y la secuencia de texto solo tiene números `int`.

Sin embargo, el problema se genera cuando intento entrenar el modelo, obtengo:

`loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

**¿Cómo se ven los datos y las etiquetas x, y con los resultados?**

```py
print(validation_label_seq)
[[ 5]
 [10]
 [ 4]
 [ 4]
 [15]
 [12]
 [ 1]...]

print(validation_padded[0])
maxlen = 240
array([  23,  353,  147,  677,    1,    1,  409,   10,  845, 1530,    1,
        103,  107,  998,  117, 1389,   25,    1,   28, 1889,  165,    1,
       1520,   49,  718,   65,   55,   34,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
          0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,...], dtype=int32)
```

```py
print(train_label_seq)
[[ 8]
 [ 9]
 [ 3]
 [ 7]
 [ 4]
 [10]
 [15]
 [11]...]

print(train_data_padded[0])
maxlen = 240
array([ 19, 301, 133, 302, 562, 133,  28, 563, 895, 896, 897, 118,  99,
       564, 397,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,
         0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0...], dtype=int32)
```

```py
results = model.evaluate(validation_padded, validation_label_seq)

test = validation_padded[10]
predict = model.predict_classes([test])
print(predict[1])

59/59 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/sample - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
[0]
/tensorflow-2.1.0/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/sequential.py:342: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in greater
  return (proba > 0.5).astype('int32')
```

```py
print(predict)

array([[0],
       [0],
       ...
       [0],
       [0]], dtype=int32)
```

---

**¿Qué ya intenté?**

- Ya intenté cambiar a diferentes optimizadores
- reducir el batch size
- Verifique errores de valores en el dataframe y en las secuencias, como en los paddeados de `x` e `y` (datos de entrenamiento y validación).

---

**Output esperado:**
Tal vez estoy construyendo mal el modelo, así que explicaré cuál es la idea principal. Me gustaría obtener un output o o dieciséis outpus, que determina el `accuracy` del tipo de personalidad.

```
1 output:
INTP: 89%

16 outputs:
ENTP: 5% | INTP: 81% | INTJ: 1% | ...
```

**Dataframe:** [mbti_df.csv](https://github.com/GUNTERMAXIMUS/mbti/blob/master/mbti_new.csv)

*Cualquier sugerencia para mejorar la pregunta será considerada.*